# Best attack when practicing the Segovia Scales

Tags: scales, classical-guitar

I studied classical guitar for two years but that was 25 years ago. I want to do it more seriously this time and I got the methods that I started with which include the First, Second and Third lessons by Julio Sagreras, the 120 Right Hand Studies by Mauro Giulliani and the Segovia Scales.

My question is the following, should the scales be played using "rest strokes", "free strokes" or both?

Thank you.

Comment: Why should it matter?  They are exercises, not compositions.

Comment: @hpaulj - It matters because each exercise should have specific objectives. Otherwise you are only doing them for fun.

Comment: Jason Vieaux, in his tube video, says that the distinctive thing about the Segovia book is the left hand shifting. Gmajor shifts twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would expect to play them all apoyando, or rest stroke.

The sheet music I have of this says apoyando at the top, which makes this very simple.

I am surprised your copy doesn't state this...

Comment: Looking at the 120 studies, I'm not sure at all whether the lower notes need to be stopped to play the next, or the other two for that matter, since they all constitute the notes from a single chord. Reason I say this is that I inherited a student (grade V) whose former teacher made him play such stuff exactly as writ. It sounded rather stilted, and I played it leaving notes ringing, which improved it. On asking the exam board, the reply was that it was much easier to write it in this manner, but most players would play it like I did, as it sounded far more musical...

Comment: ...Not exactly the point in the question, but closely related, I believe. Also, since they are merely exercises, what would be wrong with playing them both ways, anyway?  The Segovia scales are apoyando, as stated, and basically, scales aren't played with any notes left ringing, anyhow...

Comment: Apoyando will only dampen the last note on a string when descending.